# Unit testing monkey patch in Angular (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkABC'))

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm attempting to unit test my setStep() method in angular using Jasmine but I keep getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkBusiness') thrown` which prevents me from continuing the test.

This is the function in the **component.ts**:

```
  get userBusiness(): string { return  this.auth &&  this.auth.user && this.auth.user.Source; }

setSteps() {
    if (this.userBusiness.checkBusiness('ABC')) {
      this.items = steps['ABC'];
      if (this.application.process.onboarding.status !== 'complete') { this.show = true; }
    } else {
      this.items = steps['DEF'];
    }
  }
```

**checkBusiness()** method is defined as a monkey patch to the String prototype class:

```
Interface String {
  checkBusiness(...args: string[]): boolean;
}

String.prototype.checkBusiness = function(...args: string[]): boolean {
  let result = false;
  for (let arg of args) {
    const currentBusinessArray = business[this];
    if (!currentBusinessArray) {
      result = false;
      continue;
    }

    if (currentBusinessArray.includes(arg)) {
      result = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

Business is an array defined as:

```
const lob = Object.freeze( <any> {
  ABC : ['ABC', 'ABC1', 'ABC2', 'ABC3'],
  DEF : ['DEF', 'DEF1', 'DEF2', 'DEF3']
});
```

**Testing/spec** file:

```
  it('should confirm that "show" is set to true in setSteps()', () => {
    const testUserBusiness = {...testDataSvc.userABC}
    const userBusinessSpy = spyOnProperty(component, 'userBusiness').and.returnValue(testUserBusiness);
    console.log(component['userBusiness']);
    component.setSteps();
})
```

**Problem::**
I keep getting  `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkBusiness') thrown`

Any idea how to get past this? I've tried to search everywhere but there isn't something like this scenerio that I can follow.

Comment: You haven't set `component.userBusiness` in your test. So when `component.setSteps()` runs, it tries to access the property `checkBusiness` of... `undefined`, which results in an error. `undefined` has no properties.

Comment: In `beforeEach`, after setting up Testbed and getting the component, set `component.userBusiness = { checkBusiness: () => 0 }` and the error willl go away. Now `component.userBusiness.checBusiness`  will be a callable expression.

Comment: @tao Since userBusiness is read only (getter function) it won't let me assign values `Cannot assign to 'userBusiness' because it is a read-only property.` Instead, I used `Object.defineProperty(component, 'userBusiness', { value: testUserBusiness.Source });`

Comment: As far as the second comment, I tried to replicate the same thing but cannot since checkBusiness is not an object but rather just a method prototype that accepts array of strings but here's what I get `Argument of type '{ checkBusiness: () => number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropertyDescriptor & ThisType<any>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'checkBusiness' does not exist in type 'PropertyDescriptor & ThisType<any>'`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice `userBusiness` is a getter. Then why don't you set `component.auth = { user: { Source: { checkBusiness: () => 0 }}}`?

Comment: Auth service is private in the component so I cannot access it. I could mock it but also that's saying that a source is an object (when it's a string) and checkBusiness is a number (when it's actually a string of arrays).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240806/discussion-between-tao-and-avu).